# i need the <td> to sort for dynamically created table using Jquery UI Sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

```js
<script>
function createTable(){
  
 var mytable = $('<table></table>').attr({ id: "basicTable" });
 var rows = new Number($("#rowcount").val());
 var cols = new Number($("#columncount").val());
 var tr = [];
 //var color ='#'+Math.random().toString(16).substr(2,6);
 var color = 'rgba(' + (Math.floor((256-199)*Math.random()) + 200) + ',' + (Math.floor((256-199)*Math.random()) + 200) + ',' + (Math.floor((256-199)*Math.random()) + 200) + ',.8)';
 for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  //var row = $('<tr></tr>').attr({ class: ["class1", "class2", "class3"].join(' ') }).appendTo(mytable);
  var row = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo(mytable);
  for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {

   $('<td></td>').text("0").css('background-color', color).appendTo(row); 
  }   
 }
 //console.log("TTTTT:"+mytable.html());
 mytable.appendTo("#box");        
 
  
}
  
</script>

<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#box" ).sortable({ cursor: "move", placeholder: "highlight" });
    $( "#box" ).disableSelection();
  });
</script>
```

```css
table{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 3px;
  border-spacing: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
 }
 table td{
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
 }
 .highlight {
         border: 1px solid #eee;
         font-weight: bold;
         font-size: 45px;
         background-color: #eee;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
Row :<input type="text" id="rowcount" />
Column :<input type="text" id="columncount" />
<input type="button" onclick="createTable();" value="Create Table" /><br/><br/>
<div id="box">
</div>
```

Here is my code where i am creating the tables dynamically, lets say if i create 3 tables i can drag and drop these 3 table.

But i need the td's that are created within the table dynamically to sort in the similar fashion.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: sort according to what criteria?

Comment: i mean swapping between two columns both horizontally and vertically..